# MSVS : C++ : Allegro 5 template : Agui GUI API : How to setup includes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, include, allegro5

I use the Allegro 5 library to work with graphics in C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio. I found this great Allegro 5 template called "Agui GUI API" but have struggled to understand how to set it up. I am an extreme beginner when it comes to setting up the coding environment. The following would help me a lot.

Recommendation where to keep the Agui files and if I copy them for each new project?

How do I include them in MSVS so that everything will compile and run from agui_example.cpp?

Files: https://code.google.com/p/agui/

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for here:

[Windows, Visual Studio 2010 and Allegro 5 - Allegro Wiki](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2010_and_Allegro_5)